# Unique tab/instance browser?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, browser-tabs, single-instance

I'm helping my grandma start using a computer,she has trouble understanding when her double clicks are registered with the OS and often ends up clicking more times that necessary.Since the only shortcuts she use are 5 Firefox bookmarks in her Windows desktop, sometimes she ends up with 3 Firefox instances with, say, 2 or 3 tabs per instance, all for the same website.

So I was wondering if there's any browser/extension (for Windows, preferably) that supports any mode of unique-instance-and-tab, so she doesn't have trouble with this.

Having an option to "force-open" a second tab/instance would be a plus, but the default behavior should be to use just one tab in a unique window/instance.

Hacks and "complex" setups are not a problem, the important point is to have it *really* simple for using.

Comment: I have never mastered the "double-click", it's always seemed too much like hard work. Get her a mouse with a roller button and change it's click action to emulate "double-click".

Comment: Well, actually I've already set the option to use single clicks (the one that makes icons like hyperlinks), but still she sometimes long-presses the button, and perhaps move the mouse, so the OS interprets it as trying to move the icon, I think. Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 22.0 has many options for tabs. See Tools menu -> Options:
Uncheck the boxes for
`Open new windows in a new tab instead`
`Always show the tab bar`
Now, bare html links usually replace whatever page you're looking at. Pressing `Shift+click` will open a tab in a new window.